# c# error : Additional information: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to make an application for support of my "Account" team and I am having problem with collation changer. Here is the code:

```
private string CollationQuery(string DBName, string FileDir, string CollationName)
{
    return string.Concat(new string[]
    {

    //Here have some query and code again:
    }
}


    private SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
    private void executeFiles(string targetDirFirstStage, string targetDirSecondStage, SqlConnection sqlConn)

        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirFirstStage);
            FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = files[i];
                bool flag = fileInfo.Extension == ".sql" || fileInfo.Extension == ".SQL";
                if (flag)
                {
                    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(sqlConn));

                        string sqlCommand = fileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
                        server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCommand);
                        server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();

                }
            }
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo2 = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirSecondStage);
            FileInfo[] files2 = directoryInfo2.GetFiles();
            for (int j = 0; j < files2.Length; j++)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo2 = files2[j];
                bool flag2 = fileInfo2.Extension == ".sql" || fileInfo2.Extension == ".SQL";
                if (flag2)
                {
                    Server server2 = new Server(new ServerConnection(sqlConn));

                        string fullName = fileInfo2.FullName;
                        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileInfo2.FullName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
                        string sqlCommand2 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        server2.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCommand2);
                        streamReader.Close();
                        server2.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();

                }
            }
        }
    private string myDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\RDBS\\Satage1\\";

    private string myDirSecondStage = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\RDBS\\Satage2\\";
    private void changeCollationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

                    con.server = this.server;
                    con.user = this.user;
                    con.password = this.password;
                    con.OpenConnection();

        string value = this.CollationQuery("TRZPro_17083118563804", this.myDirSecondStage, this.cbCollation.SelectedItem.ToString());
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(this.myDir + "TRZPro_17083118563804_step1.sql", false);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(value);
        streamWriter.Close();
        this.executeFiles(this.myDir, this.myDirSecondStage,this.sqlConn);


        con.conn.Close();

    }
```

The error is in this line :

```
this.executeFiles(this.myDir, this.myDirSecondStage,this.sqlConn);
```

and the error is :

> "Method not found: 'Void
>    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server..ctor(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection)'."

I have added reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` with version 13.100.0.0. 
Also Tried with  version 13.0.0.0 and 12.0.0.0 but getting same error.

Comment: There is at least missing a closing bracket from teh Concat function in your example code. I asume the parsing is busted up and at that point ,even parser errors become intelligible. You are also not properly closing/disposign off connections via a using statement or try/finally block.

Comment: This not help me.

Comment: Do you have assembly redirects in the configuration file?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to do this :|

Comment: That code now makes even less sesne. You close the function CollationQuery before you even close off the Concat call. And the rest of the code is just standing directly in the class, where it does not belong. Please provide the actually code so we can find the actuall issue. The first 7 lines alone can not compile, how could the rest ever hope too?

Comment: Sorry but the code is too big for here. Can i send a project?